# Python - Does a class method inherit the class parameters?

Tags: python, class, methods, statsmodels

In python, I'm trying to understand the StatsModel [Linear Mixed Effects Models](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/mixed_linear.html).

The model class is:

```
class statsmodels.regression.mixed_linear_model.MixedLM(endog, exog, groups, 
                                                        exog_re=None, use_sqrt=True, 
                                                        missing='none', **kwargs)
```

which has a 'groups' parameter. My question is

Does a class method inherit the class parameters?

The reason for asking is, for the class [methods](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.mixed_linear_model.MixedLM.html#statsmodels.regression.mixed_linear_model.MixedLM) they have the method [from_formula](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.mixed_linear_model.MixedLM.from_formula.html#statsmodels.regression.mixed_linear_model.MixedLM.from_formula) which does not include the 'groups' parameter. But in the [example](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/umich.box.com/shared/static/6tfc1e0q6jincsv5pgfa.ipynb) code they write,

```
model = sm.MixedLM.from_formula("Weight ~ Time", data, re_formula="Time", 
                                groups=data["Pig"])
```

which includes the 'groups' parameter inside the 'from_formula' method, hence my question,

Does a class method inherit the class parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure python concepts to accept the *args and **kwargs in class/ function. If we don't how many parameters is required to pass to any class or function we use args or kwargs. Please go through this link [args and kwargs](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/). I seen the internal design [from_formula](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/regression/mixed_linear_model.py), it's looking for groups as kwargs.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there are no "class parameters" at all. There are arguments of constructor.

As described [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.mixed_linear_model.MixedLM.from_formula.html#statsmodels.regression.mixed_linear_model.MixedLM.from_formula),  args and kwargs are passed to model (constructor -  ____init____ method). 
And then the model's object returns. This method is hiding some actions from you,  but if you know what you are doing you can pass some arguments as if you are passing them to constructor.

These arguments are optional.

> args : extra arguments
>
> These are passed to the model
>
> kwargs : extra keyword arguments
>
> These are passed to the model with one exception. The eval_env keyword
>   is passed to patsy. It can be either apatsy.EvalEnvironmentobject or
>   an integer indicating the depth of the namespace to use. For example,
>   the default eval_env=0 uses the calling namespace. If you wish to use
>   a “clean” environment set eval_env=-1.